# TouchPunch Not Re-Ordering Items In Sortable List

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-touch-punch, touch-punch

I have a JQueryUI Sortable list in a web application, however this doesn't work when used on a mobile device - attempting to re-order the items instead just scrolls the page.

The solution to this appears to be to use [TouchPunch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/). When implemented, this allows the user to drag items from the list, however it does not re-order them. If item 3 is dragged to the top of the list, and dropped, instead of replacing item 1, it just returns to its original position.

I am using a standard implementation of TouchPunch.

I have tried the demos on the website from the same device, and these work perfectly.

Has anyone encountered this, and is there something I'm missing?

I'm using JQueryUI 1.10.4 and JQuery 1.10.2, while the demos use JQuery 1.8.

Comment: Yes, with the big code example that you provide we can help you a lot! Oh wait. There's not code example.... Please, read this **before** ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I found the issue.

The `jquery.validate` plugin appears to be interfering with the TouchPunch plugin. Removing the validation plugin causes it to start working.